# Isinstance for interface in jni

Tags: java, java-native-interface

how do I achieve same functionality as InstanceOf in jni for the interface. JNi works only for the class object. But java keyword works with interface as well.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces also have class objects associated with them, so you *can* use [`IsInstanceOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#isinstanceof) for interfaces. For instance, the following program checks if a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is an instance of the interface [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) (which it is):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Test";
    System.out.println(m(CharSequence.class, s)); // prints 'true'
}

public static native boolean m(Class<?> cls, Object o);
```

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Main_m(JNIEnv *env, jclass dc, jclass intf, jobject o) {
    return (*env)->IsInstanceOf(env, o, intf);
}
```